# The argument type 'RequestOptions' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Options'

Tags: flutter, dart

updating one of our dev environments and now going in circles with this issue.  Has anyone seen it before that can offer some pointers?  Many thanks

> Launching lib/main.dart on sdk gphone64 x86 64 in debug mode...
> Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
> lib/RestClient/UserAllGameClient.g.dart:41:18: Error: The argument
> type 'RequestOptions' can't be assigned to the parameter type
> 'Options'.
>
> - 'RequestOptions' is from 'package:dio/src/options.dart' ('../../Flutter/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/dio-4.0.0/lib/src/options.dart').
> - 'Options' is from 'package:dio/src/options.dart' ('../../Flutter/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/dio-4.0.0/lib/src/options.dart').
>   options: RequestOptions(
>   ^

```
  Future<List<dynamic>> getUserAllGames() async {
    const _extra = <String, dynamic>{};
    SharedPreferences pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    Map<String, String> headers = {
      HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: "application/json",
      HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: "Bearer ${pref.getString("token")}",
    };
    
    final response = await _dio.get('game/all',
        options: RequestOptions(
            method: 'GET',
            headers: headers,
            extra: _extra,
            baseUrl: baseUrl)
    );
    print(response);
    return response.data;
  }
}
```

Comment: show where you call function and where you use data

Answer (score 0):

You have to change `RequestOptions` to `Options(Dio)`

```
options: Options(
  method: 'GET',
  headers: headers,
  ...
)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is new generator for dart-dio with "null-safety": "dart-dio-next"
https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/generators/dart-dio-next

Seems it works!

Answer (score -1):

We have to use `Options` going forward. Check [API document](https://pub.dev/documentation/dio/latest/dio/Options-class.html) for more information. Here is modified request:

```
final response = await _dio.get('game/all',
    options: Options(
        method: 'GET',
        headers: headers,
        extra: _extra,
        baseUrl: baseUrl)
);
```